# How can I select my agent in microsoft azure CI pipelines using azure-pipelines.yml

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have this script:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: Mobile-Pool
  agent: 'MacMini3-AMS'
  vmImage: 'MacMini3-AMS'

steps:
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx4096m'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: 'clean assembleDebug testDebugUnitTest'

# Bash
# Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'filePath'
    filePath: 'run-tests-on-emulator.sh'

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx4096m'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: 'connectedDebugAndroidTest'
```

I am running my own on-premise hardware. I have a **MacMini3** and a **MacMini2**. The MacMini2 doesn't compile properly, and I want to run on the MacMini3. How can I change the yaml script to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **[Demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)** to make sure that the capabilities your pipeline needs are present on the agents that run it.

```
pool:
  name: MyPool
  demands:
  - myCustomCapability   # check for existence of capability
  - agent.os -equals Darwin  # check for specific string in capability
```

In your scenario, you can use `Agent.Name` or `Agent.ComputerName` demand.

Comment: It now runs on Agent: MacMini3. So this question is answered. But the problem turns out to not be the machine...